# TsLint Rule for `xit` and `it.only`

Tags: typescript, jestjs, cypress, tslint

Is there a TsLint Rule to highlight a given test, if the test uses `it.only`or `xit` ?

Comment: [ban](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/ban/)?

Comment: YES!!!
Thats totally it, thank you.
You should post it as Answer, so I can mark it